# How do I export file excel is read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a file excel by StringBuilder. How can I set read-only for file excel.

this's my code :

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "FileName" + DateTime.Now + ".xls");
```

Comment: Easy answer is no .! But you may do this if you use Open XML to create excel file

Comment: Learning open xml is not that easy. but once you learn, it would be really helpfull.

Comment: Open XML doesn't help here, since it has nothing to do with the file attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to protect the workbook instead of making it read-only. File attributes are not preserved over HTTP, so there is no way to force a client to set the read-only attribute on the file (and if you could, a client could easily remove it).

There are options to make the workbook protected on the server, but [Microsoft discourages the use of Office in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), so you have to look for other options, like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you open the Excel via C#?
If you can; open the file and run vba with

```
SetAttr("TESTFILE", vbReadOnly)
```

and close the file.